# Google Places API query

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I am using the Place Searches from the Google Places API and wanted to know how the JSON results are returned/ordered.
E.g. are the list of places returned in a random order within the results array; or are they returned in order of nearest distance to the specified location i.e. with the first result in the results array being the nearest place to the specified location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is determined by the `rankby` parameter, which lets you choose either prominence (best search result match) or distance.

More info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: Thanks @Mano, I remember seeing by prominence before, but wanted to know if there was a way by specifying the distance as well. I don't remember seeing the `rankby` parameter before, maybe its something new they have recently added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This has been added to the API, please use the 'rankby=distance' instead of 'radius' in your Place Search Request as described in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests